# Comapring Objects of TreeSet and HashSet

Tags: java, set, equals

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Snehal", "Masne", "Anything", "Else");

HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(list);

System.out.println("Equality  = " + hashSet.equals(treeSet));  // returns True
```

How the equals() is evaluating the result by comparing diff structures? How come its true? Is just Hashcode being compared? If so, how come its same?

Comment: "Is just Hashcode being compared" No. Hash codes are not and should not, by definition, be used to test equality. Hash codes are within a finite space (32 bits) and [hash collisions are possible](https://learncryptography.com/hash-functions/hash-collision-attack).

Comment: @Michael nitpick: in this case since `HashSet` is based on a `HashMap`, hashCode will be called.

Comment: @Eugene Of course you're right, it is called. But that alone is not enough to guarantee equality and any matching hash of the elements will be followed by a call to `equals`. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Michael exactly as I said in my answer..

Answer (score 4):

The Javadoc of `Set` has the answer:

boolean java.util.Set.equals(Object o)

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). **This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface**.

As long as the two `Set`s have the exact same elements, it doesn't matter if they have different implementations of the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Underneath [`AbstractSet#equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractSet.java#AbstractSet.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) calls [`containsAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29). For every single element this method checks it's presence in the other `Set`:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c)
        if (!contains(e))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This will call `HashSet#contains` that looks like this:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return map.containsKey(o);
}
```

Notice that since `HashSet` is nothing more then a `HashMap` with a dummy value - `hashCode` does gets called, but only to find the bucket of where it might be - the comparison is still using `equals`